# Should I convert this dropdown selection to radio buttons or make it work with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I recently managed to get dropdown selection to work by dynamically ouputing some data from php and using jquery to disable certain options in the dropdown depending on the stock quantity for my ecommerce site.

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/osipe5/2/edit

The issue now is that I want to have the selection displayed as a radio button for now and eventually use css to to style it similar to something like this: http://jsbin.com/uwuje (posted by another SO user)

So my question is: Should I convert the dropdown entirely into a chained radio button selection or do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yJTdF/ (posted by another SO user) where radio buttons are generated by jquery and hide the dropdown using css?

I am concerned about usability and cross-browser issues.

Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a dropdown? If there are only 4-6ish options then a listing of radio buttons is fine.  Keep It Simple both for the user and for yourself.  It will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first dropdown only has 4-6 items in it then radio buttons will be fine for the first one.

You can use radio buttons for the first one and a dropdown for the next.

There is no rule that says they both must be the same.  Experiment what might look/work better.  Ask your co-workers their opinion.  If you have a designer (other than yourself) available, ask them.

Most importantly, keep it simple.  Radio buttons alone can be used to update the content in the other dropdown.  A hidden dropdown should not be needed to do that.

Comment: Sorry but not the answer I was looking for. I am more interested in hearing about technical side of things using jquery to change dropdown selection via dynamically created radio buttons. Issues such as cross-browser and other aspects of things.

Comment: @Eddy, that's not what you asked above ;)  jQuery will provide the best cross browser solution.  In this case you would want to use `onchange` events (or 'onclick' for radio buttons) that would then change the second dropdown as desired when the first is changed or radio button is selected. With that said every developer should always test their solutions to ensure it's compatible across all necessary browsers.  What have you tried so far?